# Error while setting up ldap replication

Tags: ldap, replication, ubuntu-12.04, openldap

I'm trying to set up LDAP replication according to the directions on [Ubuntu's site](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/serverguide/openldap-server.html#openldap-server-replication). I went through all the directions for setting up the provider without any trouble. But when I try to set up the consumer, I'm running into an error. I'm trying to import this ldif file:

```
dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcModuleLoad
olcModuleLoad: syncprov

dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcDbIndex
olcDbIndex: entryUUID eq
-
add: olcSyncRepl
olcSyncRepl: rid=001 provider="ldap://myserver.mycompany.com" bindmethod=simple binddn="cn=admin,dc=mycompany,dc=com" 
 credentials=mypassword searchbase="dc=mycompany,dc=com" logbase="cn=accesslog" 
 logfilter="(&(objectClass=auditWriteObject)(reqResult=0))" schemachecking=on 
 type=refreshAndPersist retry="60 +" syncdata=accesslog
-
add: olcUpdateRef
olcUpdateRef: ldap://myserver.mycompany.com
```

When I run `ldapadd -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -c -f consumer.ldif` I get this error:

```
modifying entry "olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config"
ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
    additional info: Base DN "accesslog" is not within the database naming context
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

FWIW, the cn=accesslog database does exist on the provider machine and it is being populated any time changes are made.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just a guess are you sure this "syncdata=accesslog" reference to accesslog is not the problem?

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, because accesslog is listed as one of the few valid values for syncdata in the [documentation](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconfig.html). But unfortunately still don't know what IS the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had previously thought that I do not need to manually create the dc=mycompany,dc=com database on my consumer server, because I thought it would be created as part of ldap's replication. It turned out that I needed to create dc=mycompany,dc=com manually on the consumer first, then the LDIF file imported and replication started as expected.